# Where does Ubuntu stash saved user ids and passwords?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, webdav

On my Ubuntu 9.10 system I can connect to a WebDAV folder using "Places > Connect to Server..." then setting "Service type" to "WebDAV (HTTP)", filling in the Server, Port, Folder and User Name, then hitting Connect.  At this point I get prompted for the password with 3 options - "Forget password immediately", "Remember password until you logout" and "Remember forever".

My question is this - if I select "Remember forever", where does the information get stored?

The reason for asking is that I've been messsing around with the accounts on my WebDAV server and I'd like to check/remove some of the caches information.

Comment: Your question is really about where firefox stores passwords, not ubuntu.

Comment: No, it really is about where Ubuntu stores passwords.  Nothing to do with Firefox, which doesn't support the dav:// protocol at all (at least, not when I tried it yesterday).  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 9.10: Applications, Accessories, Passwords and Encryption Keys.

But, this question is better suited for Super User, so I'm going to vote to redirect your question there.

Comment: The actual program is called seahorse and you can finda good introduction to it here: http://www.debianadmin.com/ssh-key-authentication-using-seahorse-gui.html